# magento2 unable to override custom search engine- getting blank page

Tags: magento2

here is my full di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />    

<preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\Module\Block\CatalogSearch\Layer" />

<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Catalog\Resource\Product\Collection" />

</config>
```

**In Vendor\Module\Model\Engine.php**

```
$current_list_mode = $this->layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
```

**In \Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as ToolbarModel;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    protected $tglssearchHelper;

public function __construct(
    /* passing all Constructors parameters to the parent class -Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php*/
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    ToolbarModel $toolbarModel,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    ProductList $productListHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper,      
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
)  {
        $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
        $this->_toolbarModel = $toolbarModel;
        $this->_urlEncoder = $urlEncoder;
        $this->_productListHelper = $productListHelper;
        $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
        $this->_registry = $registry;


        parent::__construct($context,$catalogSession,$catalogConfig,$toolbarModel,$urlEncoder,$productListHelper,$postDataHelper,$data);
   }

  public function getAvailableOrders()
{
    echo 'availablOrders';

}
```

But still im not able to override the custom block for my custom search engine:( 
my layout file name : **catalogsearch_catalogsearch_resultcontroller.xml**

Controller path is: 
**Vendor\Module\Controller\CatalogSearch\ResultController**

**My system.log says:**

Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []

I get a blank page when i search for the products. please help where am i wrong!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom block calling in di.xml Preference is like

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
```

I tried it is working

**di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Test" />
```

**Custom Block**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

    class Test extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    {
         public function getAvailableOrders()
         {
              echo 'test';
              exit;
         }
    }
```

Then ran `php magento setup:upgrade`, I run the product list page ...:)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I tried tat..  but I get an error cause that namespace is aliased by ToolbarModel

Comment: in Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar the namespace is given as Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as ToolbarModel ... So I thot it's the alias instead of using the whole class path in di xml, I gave just "ToolbarModel" ... Pls correct me

Comment: i corrected it, my error was i had given Model instead of Block but even after it, my core block is getting overriden

Comment: have updated the question and also posted new question @Krishna

Comment: I did the same way in etc di ran setup upgrade...could you please check this :   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122625/magento2-unable-to-render-products-using-custom-search-plugin

Comment: any update on the new link?

Comment: i tried the way you have shown except that Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block\Test  is replaced with Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar, i feel the procedure is correct, but im not getting where it is going wrong. so help needed

Comment: Sure will go with new issue, Make the question as clear as possible to get quick grasp of others ( not now if any ).

Comment: i have created a chat room for the same ... it would be helpful if we discuss it over there?   http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41613/magento2-blank-page-for-custom-search-plugin